# Set cookie in sub folder in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have one domain as `www.test.com` and I have one folder in this domain named "test1".

I am able to create and read cookie at `www.test.com` but unable to create cookie in `www.test.com/test1`.

I want to set cookie in `index.php` file of `www.test.com/test1`.
Please help.

I have tried  with following code and many others but its not setting cookie.

```
setcookie(
    "normal_id",
    '1',
    time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), 
    '/' 
);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Is this your complete code? Have you enabled full error reporting? What tools are you using to verify the HTTP header is not being generated?

Comment: There is no error in the page.Same cookie set function is working at `www.test.com` domain.

Comment: Sorry for asking questions but, seriously, I don't do it to be picky or annoy you. Your code *is* correct and, unless you provide further details, there's no way to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
setcookie('hogename','hogeval',time()+10000,'/test1'); // name, value, expire, path
```

[http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: @ArpiPatel - This code does different things than yours. You say you tried both. Then, what do you want the cookie path to be?